# NavBarItems are missing in a FormXml - Microsoft Dynamics CRM

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015, dynamics-crm-2016

I noticed that `//FormXml/forms/systemform/form/Navigation/NavBar/NavBarItem` (Navigation Bar Items) created automatically by CRM are missing in the FormXml. They appear there if you customize those navigation items, for instance: change labels or remove/add same items.
Does anyone know if there is a way to locate those "*missing*" navigation items without making customization to them?
I am doing a parsing of a FormXml in a **Console Application (C#)**.
I tested it in CRM 2015 and 2016 and not sure about earlier versions if there was the same behaviour.
Interesting, from where `Xrm.Page.ui.navigation` gets those "*missing*" items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are seeing a *delta*, only containing the differences between the default (managed) state of the CRM organization and your customizations.

How navigation bar items are displayed is mainly controlled by the 1:n relationship settings. These are configurable on the Relationship form, section "Navigation Pane Item for Primary Entity":

- display name (settings Display Option and Custom Label)
- position (Display Area and Display Order)

In the customization.xml file you can find these settings in the `EntityRelationshipRoles` nodes (path is `ImportExportXml/EntityRelationships/EntityRelationship/EntityRelationshipRoles`.

The EntityRelationships always accompany the entities that are included in the customizations.xml.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've already started looking at the relationships while waiting for any response and yeah, I am thinking the same way as you described. The problem with this approach arises when you look at the navigation items such as `Connections`, `Audit History`, `Closed Activities` and etc.. they seems to be "hardcoded".. even the ids of those items contain a word `hardcoded`. Or I'm mistaken and there is a logical algorithm?

Comment: You're right, some built-in relationships are not in the customizations.xml, so you may need to reconstruct the complete picture by taking the appropriate Entity-properties into account as well.

Comment: Yes, almost everything is clear: I will need to look at 1:N and N:N relationships and Entity Settings. Only one interesting thing, I did not enable `Auditing` for my Entity but still `Audit History` item is shown (at least in CRM 2016).